# How to replace words with Parallel arrays

Tags: java

Hello i am new to this forum.  I am fairly new to Java.  I am  trying to convert USA to UK words so that when i input a sentence containing any of the USA words, the output will be will be the sentence but replaced with UK words.  This is my attempt:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PArraystest
{
    public static void main(String [] arg)
    {
    String[] wordUSA = {"Cell", "Elevator", "Fries", "Gasoline", "Faucet"};
    String[] wordUK = {"Mobile", "Lift", "Chips", "Petrol", "Tap"};
        String changeUK = "";
        String sent;
        sent = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What name do you want to search for?");
        for (int i = 0; i < wordUSA.length; i++)
        { 
            if (sent.contains(wordUSA[i]))
        {

                sent.replace((wordUK)[i],(wordUSA)[i]);
            //break;
        }
        }
            //if (changeUK.equals(""))
            //System.out.println(" was not found.");
            //else
            System.out.println(sent);   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to use assign the string returned from `replace` to `sent` again, or `sent` will be unchanged`.
2. The `replace` method is `public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`, so the `oldChar` US word should come first, followed by the UK word.

This is the correct line: `sent = sent.replace(wordUSA[i],wordUK[i]);`

Comment: -1 this suggestion has aleady been made multiple times. No need to clutter the forum with a duplicate answer.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed when I was checking something. Although I've noticed that no one mentioned that `wordUSA[i]` should come first, given the functionality that was desired.

Comment: The main problem is that the replace method returns a new String. Good catch for the order of the parameters. Normally you would add that as a comment to an existing answer. I believe you don't have enough points to add a comment so you would need to mention this as an answer so I have changed my down vote to an up vote! +1

Comment: Thanks very much Corey, and yes, wordUSA[i] needs to be first.  Very basic error by myself!  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The replace method returns a new String with the replaced text:

```
//sent.replace((wordUK)[i],(wordUSA)[i]);
sent = sent.replace((wordUK)[i],(wordUSA)[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

First, you should assign the replaced string back to `sent`.

Second, you should use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole framework of functionality devoted to this in Java called internationalizaion (i18n)

While the sample below is primarily for generation origianlly I thought I'd point it out because you could probably devise how to run it in reverse as well.

Here's a snippet that shows the proper way to go about this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/after.html
(all code below is theirs and not my own)

**Note that to run this you'll need the resource files from the site or the versions I have provided below from the site**

```
import java.util.*;

public class I18NSample {

    static public void main(String[] args) {

        String language;
        String country;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            language = new String("en");
            country = new String("US");
        } else {
            language = new String(args[0]);
            country = new String(args[1]);
        }

        Locale currentLocale;
        ResourceBundle messages;

        currentLocale = new Locale(language, country);

        messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
        System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry"));
        System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell"));
    }
}
```

MessagesBundle.properties:

```
greetings = Hello.
farewell = Goodbye.
inquiry = How are you?
```

MessagesBundle_en_US.properties:

```
greetings = Hello.
farewell = Goodbye.
inquiry = How are you?
```

MessagesBundle_fr_FR.properties:

```
greetings = Bonjour.
farewell = Au revoir.
inquiry = Comment allez-vous?
```